# Dark mode switch using HTML5 and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this simple code to turn a webpage into dark/light mode. It works fine on the page you are, but if I click any  links or buttons to redirect me from `index.html` to `test.html` for example, then the settings resets to default. Let's say I want to browse my page in light mode, and lick `test button` it goes back to dark mode. 
How do I make it remember to stay in the same mode I choose? Here is what I got.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Dark -Light Mode Switcher</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<body id="body" class="dark-mode">
<h1>Dark/Light Mode Switcher</h1>

<button type="button" name="dark_light" onclick="toggleDarkLight()" title="Toggle dark/light mode"> 
</button>

<p><a href="test.html"><button name="test">TEST PAGE</font></button></a>

<!-- partial -->
<script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Script.js

```
function toggleDarkLight() {
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var currentClass = body.className;
body.className = currentClass == "dark-mode" ? "light-mode" : "dark-mode";
}
```

Style.css

```
body.dark-mode {
background-color: #111;
color: #eee;
}
body.dark-mode a {
color: #111;
}
body.dark-mode button {
background-color: #eee;
color: #111;
}

body.light-mode {
background-color: #eee;
color: #111;
}
body.light-mode a {
color: #111;
}
body.light-mode button {
background-color: #111;
color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: Read the following: https://css-tricks.com/dark-modes-with-css/

Comment: You might want to think about using something like [**cookies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Examples) **OR** [**local storage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example) for this. This way you can check the value set while navigating on your domain to set the correct theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your Script.js like below, you will obtain what you want :

```
body.className=localStorage.getItem("stateMode");
function toggleDarkLight() {
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var currentClass = body.className;
body.className = currentClass == "dark-mode" ? "light-mode" : "dark-mode";
localStorage.setItem("stateMode",body.className);
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, and works exactly as needed. Thank you for your time and help